# How can I add max length, required attributes: Yes in XML schema?

Tags: xsd

I know there are two ways to define simple elements in XML schema. How can I add only maxlength and required attribute YES to simple element definition. in the following two examples.

```
<xs:element name="Xyz">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Xyz" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your restricted text content as a global (=named) `<xs:simpleType>` then use this as a base type for `<xs:extension>` that you need when create a new type by extension to add the attribute.

Type definition of an element that has attributes must be `<xs:complexType>`. Then again if the element content can be only text or attributes but not elements, the content must be defined as `<xs:simpleContent>`. Sample code below.

```
  <!-- definition of the restricted string -->
  <xs:simpleType name="restrictedLength">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="4" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <!-- definition for the element with an attribute and text content -->
  <xs:element name="Xyz">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="restrictedLength">
          <xs:attribute name="YES" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

For more complete explanation on extending simple content elements with attribute see this:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/22/easyschema.html

Comment: <xs:simpleType name="restrictedLength">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="4" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

Comment: Do I really need to extend in this case? Can't I add attribute directly to simple type w/o extending in complex type?<xs:simpleType name="restrictedLength">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="4" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

Comment: @xyz: Yes, an element with simple type cannot contain an attribute. Or actually: `<xs:simpleType>` cannot contain an attribute definition. Therefore the element must have complex type.

Comment: Thank you jasso. But in restricted length simple type max length is 4. When i extend restricted length to different complex types, how can i change that max length depending upon the requirements? If i extend as it is in different places...the max length ll remain always as 4 rie?

Comment: For elements that don't need string restrictions you can use <xs:extension base="xs:string> (or some other suitable built-in type). for elements that require restrictions for text contents and an attribute you must first define a named type with required restrictions and then extend it. If the text restrictions differ between elements, then you need to create separate types for them as a basis for extension.

Comment: Thnx jasso..In the above example while extending restricted length if I want to change the length value from 4 to some other value..how can i override it? Is there a way not to define restricted length's value as 4 in the main schema and assign value based on the requirements in different places?

Comment: @xyz: Just like I wrote in my previous comment: create a separate simple types for elements that have differing simple type requirements.

Comment: If i want to extend the same restricted length for others but need different length value...in that case also i need to create separate simple types for each and every different length? is there a way just to change length value only when required but extend from same restricted length?